# I cant figure out my PHP problem. Can anyone with PHP codes?

Tags: php, web

when I click the submit button it gives me an error page. Here is the site http://nealconstruction.com/estimate.html

```
<?php
/* Subject and Email Varibles */

    $emailSubject = 'Estimate'
    $webMaster = 'jeffery.neal06@gmail.com'

/* Gathering Info */

 $emailField = $_POST ['email'];
    $nameField = $_POST ['name'];
    $phoneField = $_POST ['phone'];
    $typeField = $_POST ['type'];
    $locationField = $_POST ['location'];
    $infoField = $_POST ['info'];
    $contactField = $_POST ['contact'];

    $body = <<<EOD
<br><hr><br>
Email: $email <br>
Name: $name <br>
Phone Number: $phone <br>
Type Of Job: $type <br>
Location: $location <br>
Additional Info: $info <br>
How to Contact: $contact <br>
EOD;

 $headers = "From: $email\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html\r\n";
    $success = mail($webMaster; $emailSubject; $body; $headers);

/* Results rendered as html */

 $theResults = <<<EOD
<html>
<head>
<title>JakesWorks - travel made easy-Homepage</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body {
 background-color: #f1f1f1;
 font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 font-style: normal;
 line-height: normal;
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #666666;
 text-decoration: none;
}
-->
</style>
</head>

<div>
  <div align="left">Thank you for your information! We will contact you very soon!</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
EOD;

echo "$theResults";

?>
```

Comment: This really belongs on stackoverflow instead.

Comment: Don't put all the HTML in a string, just put it after `?>`.

Answer (score 2):

There are not `;` after

```
$emailSubject = 'Estimate'
$webMaster = 'jeffery.neal06@gmail.com'
```

And there are `;` between the `mail` parameters, which should be `,`.

I'd advise you to configure your server that it shows debug messages. If you don't have permission to change settings on the server, you could set up a local server on you own PC to use for developing and testing. Not getting any useful feedback on mistakes like this can make development a living hell. :)

Comment: true! debug message is very important! or, if you don't want it to shown on public. Set it to file. Ask your hosting provider, where it is.

Comment: If you are unable to change php errors due to your provider.  Add this code to your script error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

Answer (score 2):

This is your error:

```
$success = mail($webMaster; $emailSubject; $body; $headers);
```

Change it to:

```
$success = mail($webMaster, $emailSubject, $body, $headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you may have an .htaccess file that has an error in it. That is usually the main cause of 500 errors in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a server issue. Contact your system admin or web service provider. They may be able to resolve the issue.